# Xamarin.Forms unit testing of a View page fail with static resources

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build a unit test for a View page in my XF application, although I can't really find any detail around this on the web, I've gotten Xamarin.Forms.Mocks package installed, but I'm running into a snag.

Take my View page:

```
public partial class WelcomePage : ContentPage
{
    public WelcomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        WelcomeTransaction();
    }

    public async void WelcomeTransaction()
    {
        ButtonRegister.Opacity = 0;
        ButtonRegisterNewDevice.Opacity = 0;

        await Task.WhenAny<bool>
        (
          ButtonRegister.FadeTo(1, 1000, Easing.SinIn),
          ButtonRegisterNewDevice.FadeTo(1, 1000, Easing.SinIn)
        );
    }
}
```

Very simple class.

My issue is that my tests keep failing on "InitializeComponent" because I have static resources attached.

My XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms" prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" x:Class="Sandbox.Views.WelcomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="splashscreen.png" Aspect="Fill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 1, 1, 1" />
            <StackLayout Padding="15" Spacing="1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, 1, 0.5" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Button x:Name="ButtonRegister" AutomationId="ButtonRegister" Text="REGISTER" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNormal}" Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}">
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="ButtonRegisterNewDevice" AutomationId="ButtonRegisterNewDevice" Text="REGISTER A NEW DEVICE" Style="{StaticResource ButtonHighlighted}" Command="{Binding RegisterNewDeviceCommand}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ViewTest
{
    private Views.WelcomePage _welcome;

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEach()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Mocks.MockForms.Init();
    }

    [Test]
    [Category("Welcome Page View")]
    public void Can_Call_Constructor()
    {
        _welcome = Substitute.For<Views.WelcomePage>();

    }
}
```

I'm using NSubstitute, Xamarin.Forms.Mock, Moq and NUnit.

I'm trying to do this as part of a learning scenario, and would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

I put an example of this on the Xamarin.Forms.Mocks [readme](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/Xamarin.Forms.Mocks), but maybe it isn't quite clear.

To test things using `Application.Current` or its resources:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    MockForms.Init();

    //This is your App.xaml and App.xaml.cs, which can have resources, etc.
    Application.Current = new App();
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    Application.Current = null;
}
```

Assuming your main `App` is where your `StaticResource`'s are, does this solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can make unit test application current as your project's App

```
Application.Current = Activator.CreateInstance<YourProjecetNameSpace.App>();
```